# Is scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull thread-safe?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, parsing

I'm running some Scala Spark application which uses Scala JSON parsing API.

But sometimes, it stuck and hung on rarely. Thread dump of that time is like the following:

> scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.resize(HashTable.scala:257)
> scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.scala$collection$mutable$HashTable$$addEntry0(HashTable.scala:154)
> scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.findOrAddEntry(HashTable.scala:166)
> scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.findOrAddEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
> scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.put(HashMap.scala:76)
> scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.update(HashMap.scala:81)
> scala.collection.mutable.MapLike$class.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:194)
> scala.collection.mutable.AbstractMap.getOrElseUpdate(Map.scala:80)
> scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical.StdTokenParsers$class.keyword(StdTokenParsers.scala:37)
> scala.util.parsing.json.Parser.keyword(Parser.scala:113)
> scala.util.parsing.json.Parser$$anonfun$jsonObj$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Parser.scala:135)
> scala.util.parsing.json.Parser$$anonfun$jsonObj$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Parser.scala:135)
> scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anonfun$rep1sep$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Parsers.scala:771)
> ...

According to my investigation, 'JSON' is object and it extends StdTokenParsers trait which has mutable Hashtable. As I know, Spark tasks are running multi-thread in one executor, thus it seems it is possible for some concurrency problem to happen.

Is my assumption right?

Comment: `scala.util.parsing.json` was deprecated even before I started to use **Scaka**, please use a JSON parsing library and please upgrade to newer versions of the language and **Spark**.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but version upgrade is not easy for now.